# Azure IoT Hub - fail to create a layered deploy

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-suite

I'm try to create a layered deploy for an Azure IoT Hub.

Base full deployment goes ok. Here the configuration:

```
{
  "content": {
    "modulesContent": {
      "$edgeAgent": {
        "properties.desired": {
          "schemaVersion": "1.0",
          "runtime": {
            "type": "docker",
            "settings": {
              "minDockerVersion": "v1.25",
              "loggingOptions": "",
              "registryCredentials": {
                "docker": {
                  "username": "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_USERNAME_docker",
                  "password": "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD_docker",
                  "address": "docker.io"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "systemModules": {
            "edgeAgent": {
              "type": "docker",
              "settings": {
                "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.0",
                "createOptions": "{}"
              }
            },
            "edgeHub": {
              "type": "docker",
              "status": "running",
              "restartPolicy": "always",
              "settings": {
                "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.0",
                "createOptions": "{\"HostConfig\":{\"PortBindings\":{\"5671/tcp\":[{\"HostPort\":\"5671\"}],\"8883/tcp\":[{\"HostPort\":\"8883\"}],\"443/tcp\":[{\"HostPort\":\"443\"}]}}}"
              }
            }
          },
          "modules": {
            "Sender": {
              "version": "1.0.0",
              "type": "docker",
              "status": "running",
              "restartPolicy": "always",
              "settings": {
                "image": "${MODULEDIR<../Sender>}",
                "createOptions": "{}"
              }
            },
            "Module1": {
              "version": "1.0.0",
              "type": "docker",
              "status": "running",
              "restartPolicy": "always",
              "settings": {
                "image": "${MODULEDIR<../Module1>}",
                "createOptions": "{}"
              }
            },
            "Module2": {
              "version": "1.0.0",
              "type": "docker",
              "status": "running",
              "restartPolicy": "always",
              "settings": {
                "image": "${MODULEDIR<../Module2>}",
                "createOptions": "{}"
              }
            },
            "Module11": {
              "version": "1.0.0",
              "type": "docker",
              "status": "running",
              "restartPolicy": "always",
              "settings": {
                "image": "${MODULEDIR<../Module11>}",
                "createOptions": "{}"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "$edgeHub": {
        "properties.desired": {
          "schemaVersion": "1.0",
          "routes": {
            "SenderToModule1": "FROM /messages/modules/Sender/outputs/* WHERE $body.Receiver = 'Module1' INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/Module1/inputs/input\")",
            "SenderToModule2": "FROM /messages/modules/Sender/outputs/* WHERE $body.Receiver = 'Module2' INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/Module2/inputs/input\")",
            "SenderToModule11": "FROM /messages/modules/Sender/outputs/* WHERE $body.Receiver = 'Module11' INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/Module11/inputs/input\")",
            "Module1ToModule11": "FROM /messages/modules/Module1/outputs/* INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/Module11/inputs/input\")",
            "SenderToHub": "FROM /messages/modules/Module1/outputs/* WHERE $body.Receiver = 'Hub' INTO $upstream"
          },
          "storeAndForwardConfiguration": {
            "timeToLiveSecs": 7200
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Next, I've tried to create a layered deployment launching command

```
az iot edge deployment create --layered --deployment-id deploy001 --hub-name <hubname> --content ./layeredtarget.json --target-condition "tags.deviceId='TargetDevice'" --priority 2
```

Here, the **layeredtarget.json** file:

```
{
    "content": {
        "modulesContent": {
            "$edgeHub": {
                "properties.desired.routes.SenderToModule1": "FROM /messages/modules/Sender/outputs/* WHERE $body.Receiver = 'UPDATE_LAYERED' INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/Module1/inputs/input\")"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By launching powershell command i've received this error:

> {'Message': 'ErrorCode:InvalidConfigurationContent;The content provided for configuration is invalid. >Please check and try again', 'ExceptionMessage': 'Tracking ID:f716a3c452914ea4a1ad1ee958a7b2ff-G:5->TimeStamp:01/20/2021 16:14:15'}

I don't understand were i did a mistake. I followed this [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-deploy-cli-at-scale?view=iotedge-2018-06)
Does someone has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you also include the `$edgeAgent`, your layered deployment will work just fine. What I did to find this out was to re-create your deployment in the portal, checked the JSON and noticed the empty edgeAgent. I guess not many people are creating layered deployments with just a route. Neat idea though. I tested the JSON below on my hub using the CLI and it worked:

```json
{
    "content": {
        "modulesContent": {
            "$edgeAgent": {},
            "$edgeHub": {
                "properties.desired.routes.SenderToModule1": "FROM /messages/modules/Sender/outputs/* WHERE $body.Receiver = 'UPDATE_LAYERED' INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/Module1/inputs/input\")"
            }
        }
    }
}
```